# QTableView scrolling stopped after dynamic resizing

Tags: qt, qtableview, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a QTableView with a custom QSortFilterProxyModel for searching and sorting and a QSqlQueryModel for populating the table.

```
void ProxyModel::searchTable(QString name, QString type, QString date, QString time ){
    if(name_ != name)
        name_ = name;
    if(type_ != type)
        type_ = type;
    if(date_ != date)
        date_ = date;
    if(time_ != time)
        time_ = time;
    invalidateFilter();
}
bool ProxyModel::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row,
                                  const QModelIndex &source_parent) const{
    QModelIndex indName = sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               0, source_parent);
    QModelIndex indType= sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               4, source_parent);
    QModelIndex indDate = sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               2, source_parent);
    QModelIndex indTime = sourceModel()->index(source_row,
                                               3, source_parent);
    if(
              sourceModel()->data(indName).toString().toLower().contains(name_.toLower())
            &&sourceModel()->data(indType).toString().toLower().contains(type_.toLower())
            &&sourceModel()->data(indDate).toString().toLower().contains(date_.toLower())
            &&sourceModel()->data(indTime).toString().toLower().contains(time_.toLower())
       )
    {
        emit adjust();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

After  a successful search, I emit a signal from my proxy model to a slot where it adjusts the table height to fit the size of the rows.
    connect(proxyModel, SIGNAL(adjust()), this, SLOT(dataChanged()));

And when the search button is clicked

connect(ui->searchBtn, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &AllVisitedPlaces::getSearchOptions);

I call the proxy model searchTable method with search parameters

```
void AllVisitedPlaces::getSearchOptions()
{
    proxyModel->searchTable(ui->nameLineEdit->text(),
                            ui->typeLineEdit->text(),
                            ui->dateLineEdit->text(),
                            ui->timeLineEdit->text());
     adjustTableSize();
}

void AllVisitedPlaces::dataChanged()
{
    adjustTableSize();
    this->verticalHeader->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::ResizeToContents);

}

void AllVisitedPlaces::adjustTableSize()
{
     QRect rect = ui->table->geometry();
     int height = 0;
     for (int i =0; i < proxyModel->rowCount() ; i++)
         height+= ui->table->rowHeight(i);
     rect.setHeight(18 + ui->table->horizontalHeader()->height() + height);
         ui->table->setGeometry(rect);
         verticalHeader->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
}
```

The problem is, when the table re-sizes , I lose scrolling.
How can I fix that ?

Before re-sizing :
[image: Before re-sizing]
After re-sizing :

[image: After re-sizing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you expect scrolling when you've resized the table to fit its contents?

The likely problem is that your Ui is broken in other ways and the table is obscured: it has been resized, but you can't see that because whatever widget the table view sits in doesn't manage the table widget properly. But we can't tell for sure because you didn't minimize your code to provide a complete compileable example of what you're doing. We're talking about <100 lines of code in all - surely it wouldn't be a big deal to just paste such a `main.cpp` in your question. See e.g. [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18965810/1329652) or [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21569029/1329652).

This is a bad design anyway since you're presuming that the table will fit on screen. Yet it won't: once the resizing works, you'll end up with a vertically huge window that cannot be used as some of its corners will extend past the screen, with no way to reach them to see the contents or to resize the window.

Finally, once you properly use layouts in your Ui design, the `setGeometry()` call on any widget below top-level is a no-op: it's the layout that controls the child widget geometry. The solution then is not to set the widget's geometry, but to **set its minimum size instead**.

You're facing an XY Problem: you're dead set on a solution, without telling us what it is that you're trying to achieve and making sure first that what you're after makes sense (as in: that it will actually lead to a usable Ui!).

Comment: My TableView is already inside a gridLayout.
But you are right, setGeometry() is what caused the issue.

I added a vertical spacer under the table layout and set the layout stretch to [10:1] then I used setMaximumHeight() instead and It works.

I also removed redundant/bad code as for changing the size with each change in the model data and just called adjustTableSize() after all the new data is loaded.

Thank you and please pardon me, I'm just a beginner.